# Sprout vs shoot vs seedling vs sapling

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

What is the difference between sprout, shoot, seedling and sapling?Can you make them in order of growing stage.

I guess sapling is relatively later stage of an embryo of a plant as far as I read.

And how do we use them  figuratively ?

Comment: A `sprout` would be a very young plant just coming out of the ground.  To sprout is a verb that has the same feel of just being born from the earth.  A `shoot` I've only heard in regards to a young bamboo plant, though perhaps it could be used with other tree branch like plants.  A seedling feels very close to a sprout, but perhaps makes the plant feel slightly older and I think I would use it more towards trees than plants.  A `sapling` is a young tree, say more than 1 year and less than 3 years old.  Big enough that it woun't break if touched, but still young and somewhat fragile.

Comment: I agree with @Michael Dorgan. Also, we don't usually spend much time worrying about when an oak tree has graduated from a being a sprout to being a sapling, the way we would a child who is going from kindergarten into elementary school. The word _sprout_ might be used as a verb ("It looks like a maple tree has sprouted near the garden"), while _sapling_ would be more likely to be used as a noun referring to the immature tree ("Did you see the maple sapling out near the garden?"). I think _sprout_ is more commonly used for vegetable plants, while _sapling_ is more commonly used for trees.

Comment: As for using the words figuratively, a more common catch-phrase is [_germinated_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/germinate), which refers to all of these early stages of plant life. It might be used when talking about, say, **ideas**. For example: _"Nicholas slipped back into the house and rapidly put into execution a plan of action that had long germinated in his brain"_ (Saki, _The Lumber Room_).

Comment: @J.R. Funny you should refer to oak trees as maple trees came to mind when thinking of saplings.  Perhaps because I think of maple syrup coming from the `sap` of maple trees :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - I could have used _elm_ or _pine_ just as easily. I meant to use one kind of tree in my first comment, and use another kind of tree in my sample quotes. Maybe it wasn't such a good idea to pull a switch like that – I hope it won't be too confusing for others reading this question!

Comment: @J.R. `switch`?  Now you are just laying down puns  :)  BTW, if there is no objection, should I make that comment an answer?

Comment: @J.R. thanks for the example of a figurative usage. I think I can say " to germinate an idea in my mind" in a sense that "to start to think about the idea  in more detailed which came to mind before but it is  still not well organized" ..does it work when I say " to sprout an idea " too?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - answer away! This is a tricky question; I'm sure the O.P. will appreciate any good answer that sprouts up ;^)

Comment: @Mrt: Yes, you can; [other authors have used that expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+idea+sprouted%2Can+idea+germinated%2Can+idea+sprang&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Comment: Many kinds of seeds can sprout _without being planted_. Some kinds are sprouted intentionally for food (mung bean sprouts, for instance). So that's definitely the first stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *sprout* would be a very young plant just coming out of the ground. *To sprout* is a verb that has the same feel of just being born from the earth. A *shoot* I've only heard in regards to a young bamboo plant, though perhaps it could be used with other tree branch like plants. A *seedling* feels very close to a *sprout*, but perhaps makes the plant feel slightly older and I think I would use it more towards trees than plants. A *sapling* is a young tree, say more than 1 year and less than 3 years old. Big enough that it wouldn't break if touched, but still young and somewhat fragile.

Oh, and a *switch* is a very old term for a thin tree branch, usually used for corporal punishment on a young child's butt or perhaps for play sword fighting between children.  Small enough to bend easily, but not so big as to do real harm (not a cudgel.)  As this came from the comments, I figured I could explain that as well.  :)

Comment: Welcome to ELL A lot of people here really discourage the use of the 'coding' markup or format or whatever `this kind of shading` is called. It is hard on the eyes and makes posts hard to read. Most people use *this* or sometimes bold, if necessary, or just put a word in 'single'  quotation marks. Or "double". Note all the comments of J.R.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words.  Just learning the culture here.

Comment: Yup, someone gave me the same comment about the style when I arrived...